# Javascript/Mathjax/etc inside Markdown inside Reveal.JS

Tags: javascript, markdown, mathjax, reveal.js

I use reveal.js on my laptop for presentations. I use Markdown for my slides. However I cannot get things like mathjax working from within the markdown-file. Same goes for things like an animation. Can someone please explain to me (preferably with an example) how to get stuff working from within the Markdown file.

For example:

```
      <h3>The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality</h3>
      <script type="math/tex; mode=display">
      \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^n 
      a_k^2 \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2 \right)
      </script>
```

Works fine in .html, but not in my .md

Thank in advance!

Comment: You might want to add a link to a self-contained, live sample of what you've tried.

Comment: This is what's in my html-file:

        <section data-markdown="/directory/test.md"
        data-separator="^\n\n\n"
        data-separator-vertical="^\n\n"
        data-separator-notes="^Note:"
        data-charset="iso-8859-15">
 </section>
 </div>

If the markdown content is just plain html it displays as would be expected. Something different does not display.

Comment: Solved: Had to double escapes. E.g. \frac becomes \\frac et cetera.

Comment: its possible to add your answer and than accept it. so the next one finds the problem has been solved :-)

Comment: you could also use e.g. http://pandoc.org which already does that for you...